# Cannot import some modules from package

Tags: python

I know there are many stackoverflow question of this type but even after reading all those answers i could not manage to solve my problem.

Problem is, I can not import few python files from a module but i can import other files.
i have below module structure:

```
test_module   
├── __init__.py
├── keyword_extractor.py
└── word2vec
└── test3.py
```

my **__init__.py** contain below code.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join('..', 'test_module'))

import word2vec, keyword_extractor, test3
```

I am trying to import this way:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join("..", "..", "test_module"))
sys.path.append(path)
import test_module as tm
```

I can successfully import word2vec file

```
tm.word2vec.some_fuction()
```

BUT, when i am trying to import **keyword_extractor** i am getting error.

```
keywords = tm.keyword_extractor.get_keywords()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'keyword_extractor'
```

I tried to different approach like:

i added **__all__** in **__init__.py** and imported all python files from **test_module**

```
__all__=["word2vec","keyword_extractor", "test3"]
```

but still i am getting the error with **keyword_extractor**.

**keyword_extractor** contains below code:

```
def get_keywords():
    return ["keywords"]
```

Comment: change `dm.keyword_extractor` to `tm.keyword_extractor`.

Comment: I hope it's just a typo here `import test_module as tm` `dm.keyword_extractor.get_keywords()`

Comment: Yes, it was typo, sorry for that and that is not the reason of error.